# DRM-protected video streaming in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, streaming, drm

I want to perform DRM-protected video streaming similar to how Netflix does it with Silverlight, only in a WPF application.

However the MediaElement in WPF does not have a LicenseAcquirer or the ability to set a stream.

Is there a way to do this in a WPF application?

Answer (score 1):

No easy way, however it can be done.
Download Jeremy MediaKit: http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/
Then you need to build your own custom DirectShow graph and feed it to that.

You also need DirectShow Base Classes.NET to query the filters(you might be better off writing it in C++ though, if you feel like it). 
Here is a MSDN doc that explains how to write DRM protection: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Alternatively use AxWMPPlayer which works with DRM nicely, however it's not WPF specific, so yo can't rotate it or do any other functions.